# How do I pass kwargs to url when posting data? I keep getting: No ReserveMatch Error

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, django-urls

I have spent all day trying but cannot workout what I am doing wrong. I have two views, one loading the main view and one calling a modal to send an email. When I post data through the modal I get a reverse match error and not sure why. Funny enough if I empty a field in the modal it get no error as the pk is there. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. I understand that someone I am not passing the pk back to the template ones data are posted, but how do you do that? Using get_form_kwargs did not work.

Error: Reverse for 'application-update' with keyword arguments '{'pk': None}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['update/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

Template

```
{% url 'application-update' pk=application_update.id %}
{% url 'send-message' %}
```

urls.py

```
re_path(r'^update/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ApplicationViewUpdate.as_view(), name="application-update")
re_path(r'^send/$', views.SendMesssageView.as_view(), name="send-message"),
]
```

views.py

```
class ApplicationViewUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Application
    form_class = ApplicationForm
    template_name = 'update_application.html'
    context_object_name = 'application_update'
    success_url = '/update/{id}/'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ApplicationViewUpdate, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['id'] = self.kwargs['pk']
        application = Application.objects.get(id = context['id'])
        context['message'] = MessageForm()
        return context


class SendMesssageView(FormView):
    form_class = MessageForm
    template_name = 'message.html'
    context_object_name = 'send_message'
    success_url = '/send/'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['id'] = self.request.POST.get('id')
        context['pk'] = context['id']
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        mailto = form.cleaned_data['mailto']
        mailfrom = form.cleaned_data['mailfrom']
        mailcc = form.cleaned_data['mailcc']
        mailsubject = form.cleaned_data['mailsubject']
        mailmessage = form.cleaned_data['mailmessage']
        form.send_mail(mailto, mailfrom, mailcc, mailsubject, mailmessage)
        return super(SendMesssageView, self).form_valid(form)
```

print(context) from SendMessageView if mailto field is anyone@mail.com

```
{'form': <MessageForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(mailto;mailfrom;mailcc;mailsubject;mailmessage)>, 'view': <views.SendMesssageView object at 0x7f9be8041490>, 'id': None, 'pk': None}
```

print(context) from SendMessageView if when mailto field is anyone@gmail.com

```
{'form': <MessageForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(mailto;mailfrom;mailcc;mailsubject;mailmessage)>, 'view': <views.SendMesssageView object at 0x7f9c0a2e2ca0>, 'id': '6', 'pk': '6'}
```

template.html

```
<button class="btn" type="submit" value="notify" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#notify"><a>Notify</a></button>
<div class="modal fade" id="notify" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Notify</h5>
        </div>
        <form action="{% url 'send-message' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="{{ message.mailto.id_for_label }}">To:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="{{ message.mailto.html_name }}" id="{{ message.mailto.id_for_placeholder }}" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="{{ message.mailcc.id_for_label }}">Cc:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="{{ message.mailcc.html_name }}" id="{{ message.mailcc.id_for_placeholder }}" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <label for="{{ message.mailfrom.id_for_label }}">From:</label>
                <input class="form-control" name="{{ message.mailfrom.html_name }}" id="{{ message.mailfrom.id_for_placeholder }}" value="my@mail.com">
                <label for="{{ message.mailsubject.id_for_label }}">Subject:</label>
                <input class="form-control" name="{{ message.mailsubject.html_name }}" id="{{ message.mailsubject.id_for_placeholder }}" value="You are in!!">
                <label for="{{ message.mailcc.id_for_label }}">Body:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="{{ message.mailmessage.html_name }}" id="{{ message.mailmessage.id_for_placeholder }}" value="">
                   {% include 'message.html' %}
                </textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="id" value="{{id}}">Send</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<form action="{% url 'application-update' pk=application_update.id %}" method="POST">
{% include 'user_form.html' %}
</form>
```

Comment: please post related html files